# Результат уже выполненного Deferred объекта

Tags: javascript, promise

После того как был вызван метод `.resolve()` на Deferred объекте, есть ли возможность получить аргументы, с которыми был вызван `.resolve()`, имея в своём распоряжении этот самый "мёртвый"(выполненный) Deferred объект?
При этом установить `.then()` или `.done()` коллбэки до того, как он выполнится я не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете повесить then после, и в его callback прилетят ваши аргументы:

```js
const t = new Promise(resolve => resolve({test: new Date()}));

setInterval(() => t.then(res => console.log(res)), 333);
```